# How to find the sum of the digits in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    sumOfDigits("12345");
}

fun sumOfDigits(n: String) {
    val arr = n.toList()
    val arrOfInt = arr.map{ it.toString().toInt() }

    print(arrOfInt.sum())
}
```

My task is to find the sum of the digit and also the average as:

```
Sample Output:
12345

15 3.00
```

I am confused on how to code this. Can anybody please give me the easy and alternative code to the above.

Comment: `val sum = n.sumBy { it - '0' }` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 private fun sumAndAvgOfDigits(n: String) {
    val arrOfInt= n.map {"$it".toInt()}
    print("${arrOfInt.sum()} ${arrOfInt.average()}")
}

@JvmStatic
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    sumAndAvgOfDigits("12345")
}
```

Another solution:

```
private fun sumAndAvgOfDigits(n: String) {
    val arr = n.toList()
    val sum = arr.sumBy { "$it".toInt() }
    val avg = (sum.toDouble()/arr.size)
    print("$sum $avg")
}
```

Comment: is there any option/alternative to remove the map function and instead use basic for loop.

Comment: If use map I found shorter syntax n.map {"$it".toInt()}

Comment: I put another solution without map

Answer (score 2):

Using [sumByDouble](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/sum-by-double.html) and a simple count variable could work for you as well.

for example:

```
val str = "12345"
 
var count = 0
val sumOfStr = str.sumByDouble{
     count++
     it.toString().toDouble()
 }
```

and the average

```
val avg = sumOfStr / count
```

since `sumByDouble` is on a `String` the selector function look like this `selector: (Char) -> Int` and `toDouble()` on a `Char` will give you the ascii value, and thats why `it` is converted back to `String`

Comment: Beautiful. But you loose decimal part using sumOfStr / count

Comment: @СергейАфиногенов That's true, edited to `Double` cases, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for doing your task you have to do this steps:

1. convert your string into array of integers.
2. find sum of the array
3. find avg by using the array length

here is a code to help you more

```
fun main() {
    sumOfDigits("12345")


}

fun sumOfDigits(str: String) {
    val arr = str.toList().map({it.toString().toInt()})
    val sum = arr.sum()
    val length = arr.size
    val avg = sum / length
    print(sum.toString() + ' ' + avg.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a example with for loop.
the syntax you saw we used above is called lambda expression and this is kotlin way of doing it. try learning it. it will help you a lot.

```
fun main() {
    sumOfDigits("12345")
}

fun sumOfDigits(str: String) {
    val strArray = str.toList()
    var sum = 0
    
    for (i in strArray) {
        sum += i.toString().toInt()
    }
    
    val length = strArray.size
    val avg = sum / length
    print(sum.toString() + ' ' + avg.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple method to find the sum of digits in Kotlin (Using While Loop)

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
var x = 123
var sum = 0

while (x > 0) {
    var y = x % 10
    sum += y
    x /= 10
}

println(sum)

}
```

Here the answer will be: 6